# Applying stain after sanding off first coat of polyurethane

Tags: sanding, staining, polyurethane

We refurbished an old family table. We did the whole process of sanding and now have finally applied the stain (1 coat of Provinal) and applied the first coat of polyurethane. After we applied it we did a very light sand and noticed that some of the stain did not take well. I did not want this table to be dark so we did only one coat.

My question is now that some of the stain is coming up can we sand the polyurethane and apply another coat of stain and the apply the polyurethane?

I'm praying we don't have to sand it completely again and start over. The wood was a very light wood color.

Comment: what kind of wood

Comment: This is just a comment expressing compassion and sympathy!  Been there, done that.  I hate staining. Depends sooooo much on the type of wood, sometimes a conditioner will help, particularly on pine, prior to staining. But to me it's like a witches  brew of 
    Toe of frog
    Wool of bat 
    Tongue of dog

I usually tell people that I make things for, "If you want a certain color of wood, buy that wood, don't stain it.  

I'll admit, I have had luck with dyes (Transtint), you can play with it as you apply it.  If it's too light you can add more, if too dark you can wipe it off...

Comment: ...continued.:  once you get the color / dyeing locked in the way you want, you can finish it with a clear coat.  While I also hate working with lacquer because it's so stinky, it also drys really fast and is very durable so I still use it.  If going with lacquer don't buy Deft, it's only good for starting fires on burn piles.  Sherman Williams has a great lacquer product.   On the other hand, if you wanted to go with something more environmentally friendly,   I've also had decent luck with water based poly urethane.

Comment: For finishing, refinishing, and fixing finish tips, you may want to take a look at the [woodworking.se] sister site. You can sign in to that site with the same account as here and peruse the tags there. There are loads of questions about stain finishes there, and load of expertise. I'd even suggest that this question be migrated there.

Comment: Hi welcome to StackExchange. This is two completely different queries and ideally a second query should have its own Question, but what you're asking in 2 is completely subjective and subjective questions aren't a good fit for StackExchange, see [here](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Anyway let me try to break it down for you: spray poly, like everything in a spraycan, is the most expensive way to buy what's inside; however some of what we pay for is the convenience of the spray application (definite plus) and certain other advantages (e.g. long shelf life after 1st use).

Comment: I can't find any reference online to a Provinal wood stain product. Google keeps on thinking I misspelled Provincial, which is a colour available from Minwax, General Finishes & others. Is Provincial what you meant to type? If it is, please specify the finish you used (the exact product name from the can) and ditto the spray poly you used on top; both are critical to on-point Answers. But do be prepared for bad news — it is unlikely you will be able to stain successfully now, because true wood stains need to go onto bare wood to be able to soak into the wood fibres the way they're supposed to.